# Adicionar página atual aos marcadores do navegador

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, revisão-de-código, marcadores

O código em baixo apresentado encontra-se a funcionar, mas a técnica é antiga e provavelmente desatualizada face às versões atuais dos navegadores:

```
function addFavorite( a, b ) {
  title = document.title;
  url = document.location;
  try {
    // Internet Explorer
    window.external.AddFavorite( url, title );
  }
  catch (e) {
    try {
      // Mozilla
      window.sidebar.addPanel( title, url, "" );
    }
    catch (e) {
      // Opera
      if( typeof( opera ) == "object" ) {
        a.rel = "sidebar";
        a.title = title;
        a.url = url;
        return true;
      }
      else {
        // Unknown
        alert( b );
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Utilização:

```html
<a href="#" title="" onclick="addFavorite(this, 'Pressione Ctrl-D para adicionar a página aos seus favoritos');return false;">
    Adicionar aos favoritos
</a>
```

## Pergunta

O processo na sua forma atual está a decorrer eficientemente ou o mesmo pode ser simplificado e atualizado para corresponder às especificações das versões atuais dos navegadores?

Answer (score 1):

Praticamente todas funções que você usou ainda funcionam, mas não funciona em todos navegadores e nem existe solução para isto, por exemplo o navegadores Chromium (Google Chrome, Opera, Comodo Dragon, etc) bloqueiam o acesso via javascript a este método.

Você pode usa-lo, ainda e irá funcionar em uma parcela de navegadores, mas é provável que realmente estas funções sejam "desabilitadas" (descontinuadas).

O provável desuso destes métodos, a ideia é fazer com que o próprio usuário por si mesmo decida se quer ou não adicionar a página ao favoritos.

### Métodos descontinuados

- `window.external.AddFavorite` foi descontinuado desde o *Internet Explorer 10*

  <sub>Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535926(v=vs.85).aspx</sub>
- `window.sidebar.addPanel` está obsoleto desde o *Gecko 23* (tecnologia do Firefox e SeaMonkey)

  > Note que o `window.sidebar.addSearchEngine` **não** foi descontinuado

  <sub>Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sidebar</sub>

Aparentemente o único que `rel="sidebar"` foi o único não descontinuado, o motivo é que ele *funciona diferente dos outros métodos*, conforme o [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#link-type-sidebar) o atributo deve indicar que o documento referenciado (se obtido) deve ser destinado a mostrar no `contextMenu` o endereço indicado ao invés da página atual, se neste menu tiver a opção de salvar nos favoritos, isto não quer dizer que todos navegadores sigam está regra (no Opera e Chrome parece funcionar). Aparentemente ele também deve ter efeito com `<link>`, como por exemplo, se você adicionar na página `http://exemplo/blog` a seguinte tag:

```
<link rel="sidebar" href="http://examplo">
```

No momento que o usuário clicar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ao invés de usar a página `http://exemplo/blog` irá usar a página `http://exemplo` no bookmaker (realmente não consegui testar e me parece que é a mesma situação do menu de contexto, pode até ser um "padrão", mas não é totalmente respeitado).

Claro que ainda pode usar os códigos obsoletos (combinado com o `rel="sidebar"`), por exemplo se quiser manter suporte para navegadores antigos.

Se tratando do seu código (já que marcou a questão como [revisão-código](/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo)), eu só evitaria o `try/catch`, talvez usar `if` seja um melhor caminho e usaria algo menos "obstrutivo" que o atributo `onclick="..."`:

```js
function addFavorite(target) {
    var title = document.title;
    var url   = document.location;

    if (window.external && window.external.AddFavorite) {
        target.onclick = function() {
            window.external.AddFavorite( url, title );
            return false;
        };
    } else if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) {
        target.onclick = function() {
            window.sidebar.addPanel( title, url, "" );
            return false;
        };
    } else {
        target.onclick = function() {
            alert("Aperte Ctrl+D para salvar nos favoritos");
            return false;
        };
    }
}

//Use no onload ou no jquery.ready
addFavorite($("a[rel=sidebar]").get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://exemplo/teste" rel="sidebar" title="Site">Exemplo</a>
```

Note que hoje o Opera usa a tecnologia do Chrome (o Blink fork do WebKit) e talvez não funcione no Opera também, pois ele agora é da "família" GoogleChrome.