# Adicionar endereço aos favoritos via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Dando uma pesquisada no Google(e aqui) vi que era possível a um certo tempo atrás adicionar endereços aos favoritos do navegador em JavaScript, mas os métodos usados para isso foram descontinuados e eu gostaria de saber se existem novos métodos ou não é mais possível realiza-lo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar aos favoritos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83812/adicionar-aos-favoritos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso o código que encontrei nesse link: https://www.thewebflash.com/how-to-add-a-cross-browser-add-to-favorites-bookmark-button-to-your-website/

O exemplo usa `jQuery`. Testei novamente agora que estou respondendo essa pergunta para confirmar a compatibilidade, e funciona no `IE`11, `Firefox` 51 e `Chrome` 63:

```js
$('#addFavorito').click(function(e) {
    var bookmarkURL = window.location.href;
    var bookmarkTitle = document.title;

    if ('addToHomescreen' in window && addToHomescreen.isCompatible) {
      // Mobile browsers
      addToHomescreen({ autostart: false, startDelay: 0 }).show(true);
    } else if (window.sidebar && window.sidebar.addPanel) {
      // Firefox <=22
      window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkURL, '');
    } else if ((window.sidebar && /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (window.opera && window.print)) {
      // Firefox 23+ and Opera <=14
      $(this).attr({
        href: bookmarkURL,
        title: bookmarkTitle,
        rel: 'sidebar'
      }).off(e);
      return true;
    } else if (window.external && ('AddFavorite' in window.external)) {
      // IE Favorites
      window.external.AddFavorite(bookmarkURL, bookmarkTitle);
    } else {
      // Other browsers (mainly WebKit & Blink - Safari, Chrome, Opera 15+)
      alert('Press ' + (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl') + '+D to bookmark this page.');
    }

    return false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addFavorito">Adicionar Favorito</button>
```